# Facebook woke up by Google Services and don't want to be Greenified

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, greenify

Facebook and it messenger apps are eating up my Galaxy Note battery (rooted). When I Greenify them, they are activated by Google Services.

How can I stop their activation without uninstalling?

Many thanks!!

Comment: Are you saying Facebook's apps don't let the device enter into deep sleep mode? You could try Facebook lite instead also.

Comment: @xangua If I understand properly, the "Greenify" action forces the apps to fall into sleep mode and not activate "wakelock". I use WakeLockDetector which shows that Facebook and Messenger still cause "wakeup"s...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There are quite a few apps which will wake up Facebook in the background. In particular, any apps which offer to allow you to sign in via a Facebook identity. Even though you might not have signed up via Facebook, those apps will often wake up FB anyway. 
>   If you want to ensure FB doesn't wake up, then you need to install Xposed framework, enable the Greenify module in Xposed and then tick the option on Greenify for Wake-up Tracker and Cut-off. You can then disable having other apps open FB.

[Source Thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/greenify/hibernate-apps-wake-facebook-one-t3000813)